# Reinstate Monica

Tags: discussion

Monica Cellio has called for Stack Overflow to address what they did to her: [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/256777)

A number of users have [changed their username to "Reinstate Monica"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336024/how-can-we-put-pressure-on-stack-exchange-inc-without-damaging-the-community?noredirect=1#comment1110223_336024) or some variation thereof and changed their avatar as follows:

[image: reinstate Monica]

At CV, it appears that [gung](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7290/gung-reinstate-monica) and [myself](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1352/s-kolassa-reinstate-monica) have done so.

Is anyone else interested in joining us?

Comment: I am Spartacus.

Comment: Done. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: It'll be a bit confusing if lots of active users change their user names to be exactly the the same.

Comment: A substantial number of the top users on stats.SE have changed their name, their avatar or both! https://stackexchange.com/leagues/65/alltime/stats/2010-07-19/22311#22311

Comment: An [appeal](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) to raise money for Monica's legal fees, should SE force her to seek redress for defamation in court, has raised an impressive 6k$ in only half a day.

Comment: +1. I've also changed my username and avatar and my 'about me'.

Comment: I don't know how to update my username.  I will see if I can update my icon.  I am very much into joining y'all.

Comment: Listen, It is annoying to keep seeing reinstate monica. First of all, all the moderators are on volunteer basis. So the site has the right to determine who gets to be moderator and who doesnt "at will". You guys have not signed any contracts with the company so there should be no wining about it. Period.

Comment: Just as the company is free to decide how they run their site, users are (supposedly) free to choose their own avatar and username, within a few conditions that are already specified, such as restrictions on particularly offensive ones. You may find that annoying, but you have no recourse. The company might change the rules (I expect they will), but until then, I doubt they're going anywhere.

Comment: The developer survey for 2020 should have in it a distinct indicator of the effectiveness of "Reinstate Monica".  Those who have the raw data should be able to get to the concrete implication.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Monica and Stack Overflow have come to an agreement.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/256777) Monica has [posted the identical notice at her GoFundMe page](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users).

I find the agreement utterly unsatisfactory; in particular the first paragraph drips with condescension. SO exhibit the classical signs of narcissism, in particular a complete inability to empathize and apologize sincerely. Narcissists do not change, no matter how much one would hope they do.

Nevertheless, this seems to be the end of it. Monica was not reinstated, but was offered the opportunity to reapply as moderator at the six sites she originally moderated, following the new process.

> Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

As such, I will revert to my old avatar and username in the near future. There is no point in keeping the "Reinstate Monica" one. This is not the outcome I had hoped for, but see above.

I *will*, therefore, keep my updated understanding of SO, Inc.

---

Update: [Monica is leaving the network.](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2301)

Comment: There's no need to continue to have the GoFundMe information--her GFM campaign is closed. From my point of view, the result is unsatisfactory & she should still be reinstated. I recognize that SE isn't going to do anything they aren't forced to do & the lawsuit is over, but that doesn't change what should still be done. I intend to keep my avatar & username for now. I don't know if / when I'll change or to what.

Comment: I agree that Monica should be reinstated. However, based on the agreement, it sounds like she herself is not pushing for this any more (otherwise she would not have agreed to this wording), and I can't blame her. I personally do not see the point of agitating for something Monica herself apparently does not push for. I'll change back when I can bring myself to do it. It's all very sordid and not at all what I want to ruminate on this time of year.

Comment: Not quite. She stated on the agreement thread (now deleted) that she wants to be reinstated; if I recall the phrasing correctly, "to have the removal reversed". In place of that, SE has reoffered for her to go through the moderator reinstatement process that they set up after she was fired (the one she already declined). The issue there is that the reinstatement process assumes the person is guilty / was correctly removed, & her agreeing to go through that process amounts to her implicitly acknowledging that. That's why they want her to do it & she doesn't want to.

Comment: Yes, I get all this. My point is that she agreed to the agreement. Which does not include her reinstatement. I take her agreeing to it that she will not pursue reinstatement outside the new process. (And *in addition*, she will not go through the new process. Two different things.) Am I mistaken?

Comment: It's plausible that Monica sincerely believed that this agreement was the best that was going to actually happen, & so it was that or nothing. It's hard to say if the agreement is something she actually finds agreeable on its merits. Her statement that she would like the removal to be reversed implies the agreement is not fully acceptable.

Comment: Yes, Monica signed a contract. But she may not actually agree with it, and it could be something that she was forced to do. That you find 'the agreement utterly unsatisfactory' says enough how this could have gone. SE/SO has won a legal battle and has *not* reinstated Monica or has *not* shown to have done anything that would be a *satisfactory* agreement for Monica. I am not gonna remove my avatar now and do as if this *legal* settlement settles the case sufficiently. Sadly SE/SO believes it is just enough to handle it legally, but to me this is not a legal issue.

Comment: Could one change a username to 'fire some managers' or something like that? According to the cc-by sa license I have the right to my name, or a pseudonym, being associated with my contributions but I imagine there are limitations.

Comment: The offered process for reinstatement was flawed - essentially it was not in any sense designed to be a fair process - and as structured was tantamount to an admission of guilt; in the circumstances I wouldn't have accepted it either, no matter how keen I might be to get the diamond back. The company is still able to offer her reinstatement *without* conditions and it could *then* apply the actual processes for removal of a moderator. The non-acceptance of the flawed application process was not a new thing, Monica rejected it for publicly stated reasons months ago. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... as far as I can see from the announcement, the only substantive change to the various positions from well before any of us had "Reinstate Monica" avatars is that the company have removed a couple of posts of theirs that could be seen as defamatory.. Everything else seems to be exactly the same as the situation then. I'm happy they're at least taken a small step to stop defaming her (but apparently only because lawyers made that happen) -- but because nothing else has changed, I see no good reason to stop asking them to simply reinstate her (or at least offer it) to undo the ... ctd

Comment: ... capricious removal. They didn't apply proper process in removing her and there's no good reason to require she follow a process for reinstatement that builds in the assumption she *was* properly removed in the first place (but even in the case of a properly applied removal is not in a process many mods seem to think to be fair or reasonable).

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: I agree with *every single word* you write here. My point is that Monica herself apparently does not pursue reinstatement any more, given that she signed off on that agreement, and that I don't see any information to the contrary. It is against this background that I don't see the continued usefulness in calling for it. YMMV.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica, she says she still wants to be reinstated, so I'm not sure it's correct to say that she "does not pursue reinstatement any more". She did accept the agreement, whatever it entailed, but my guess is she was strongly advised that this was all she could get.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica: can you give a link where she says so? I would have expected such a statement on her GoFundMe page, and there is nothing there. Someone mentioned a post that has meanwhile been deleted. I wouldn't use deleted posts as expressions of intent.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica, she said so in a comment to her answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340914/187282), which has since been deleted. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio#comment1139733_340914) is the [dead] comment link.

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding. So why would Monica not note explicitly on her GoFundMe page that she still wants to be reinstated? I can only imagine that either (a) she does not want to be reinstated, or (b) she does want it, but the agreement she signs precludes her from publicizing it. And crucially, *there is no way for us to decide between (a) and (b)*. If this was important to her, I find it hard to believe she could not have left the possibility of at least *mentioning* it out of the agreement she signed. Which only leaves me with the conclusion that it is *not* crucial to her. ...

Comment: ... Where is my error in logic?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. *She said quite clearly that she wants to be reinstated.* Is your question just, 'why did she only say it on meta.SE & not also say it on her GFM page?' That distinction doesn't seem as important to me as it does to you. I find it suspicious that the only thing posted on the GFM page is exactly the same as the OP from the meta post. I suspect part of the non-disclosure agreement was that exact text be all that's posted there. I don't know, of course, & I don't know who deleted the comment, or why, but I do know that she said she still wanted to be reinstated.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica: Just to clarify: she wrote that she wanted to be reinstated as a comment to her answer saying that she cannot comment further? And that comment was later deleted? Can you remember what the comment said, exactly? (I think we can assume she deleted it herself, realizing/remembering that the settlement does not allow her to comment further.)

Comment: @amoebasaysReinstateMonica, yes: she wrote that as a comment under her answer that she isn't allowed to say more. It's reasonable to imagine she deleted it herself. It was a brief comment in response to someone else's comment. It said something like, 'yes, I still want to be reinstated, or more accurately, I want the removal to be reversed'. I can't see it, as I'm not a mod on meta.SE, but that was the gist of it.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica: I am sorry I am being unclear. To be honest, I don't quite see how I could make my reasoning clearer. If she still wants to be reinstated, why does she not say so at the GoFundMe site, or anywhere else she will not be deleted? If she is precluded from stating so by an agreement she signed, why did she sign the agreement? If she did sign it, I can only conclude that the agreement provided some compensation she found sufficient. My bottom line is that I don't see the point of calling for a reinstatement that Monica herself is not calling for any more.

Comment: It sounds like you're making a distinction b/t 2 places a statement can be posted. It sounds like you're saying, 'b/c she said she wanted to be reinstated in 1 place, but didn't say she wanted to be reinstated in another place, I conclude she doesn't *really* want to be reinstated'. Whereas my take is that I think she still wants to be reinstated b/c she said she does. I don't put much stock in *where* she says it.

Comment: I don't know any more about the agreement than you do, but I suspect that it implies she is very constrained in what she can say. I'm guessing it dictated what was posted on the GFM page, eg. I suspect she wanted more, but her lawyer strongly advised her that there was no way reinstatement would be part of any agreement. My guess the agreement was a simple payout & NDA, & her lawyer told her it was that or nothing. Lawyers typically get a slice of the payout, so their incentives are to settle as quickly as possible for as much as possible.

Comment: Even if they are being paid along the way, they don't typically favor a long, uncertain process. So given that she says she wants to be reinstated, I conclude that she wants to be reinstated, even though there was a (secret) agreement that didn't include reinstatement. These are all guesses. You guesses may differ & mine may be wrong. By far, the largest part of my thinking on the matter is that she says she wants to be reinstated.

Comment: No, I am not concerned about her posting her intentions at one vs. at two places. My point is that her comment at one place was deleted, so it is not visible any more, and she apparently does not make any effort to comment *visibly* that she still wants to be reinstated. "She says she wants to be reinstated" - she could do so very easily by making a comment somewhere visible. *She chose not to do so.* Without a visible statement somewhere, whether or not she still wants to be reinstated is a matter of thought-reading, which I am not good at. That's the entirety of my point.

Comment: Stephan, but the settlement is apparently prohibiting Monica to say anything this matter publicly. If so, then she cannot make a comment anywhere; I'm not sure why you say that "she could do so very easily". Doing that would probably break the terms of the settlement with whatever legal consequences this entails. (cc @gung-ReinstateMonica)

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica That said, I personally don't understand why she signed this settlement. How much money could she have been offered that she was willing to sign a pretty embarrassing agreement that effectively makes SE "win" + sign NDA that puts here in a stupid situation she is currently in when she cannot comment on that anymore. I truly cannot imagine. Can it be million(s) of dollars? If it's not a huge sum of money then why would she sign that instead of choosing "nothing"? I am really confused by that.

Comment: Those are reasonable points, @amoebasaysReinstateMonica. I don't know. None of us really know, b/c we don't know what's in the agreement. My *guess*, FWIW, is that the lawyer negotiated a quick payout & strongly encouraged her that it was this or nothing. Obviously, I don't know, but that's a fairly common set of events. She was at a substantial disadvantage, vis-a-vie the negotiation: it isn't clear her complaint would hold up legally, except for the defamation part, & that could be muddied by a good lawyer in court. Moreover, SE could have dragged this out over a long time & bled her dry.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I understand that her case might have been weak and I can easily imagine that her lawyers argued it was "this or nothing". I don't understand why she did not choose "nothing". She could have dropped her case (assuming it was hopeless) and walked away. I cannot imagine being in her shoes and choosing to sign an NDA, given all the public attention *she had herself worked hard to attract to this situation*.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I think what Stephan is getting at here, is that Monica's decision to (presumably) choose money over the possibility to keep her stance seems to undermine the cause for us to keep fighting for her.

Comment: You're an idealist, @amoebasaysReinstateMonica, that's a hard line for a normal person. I see your point, now. I suppose I'm a little more lenient.

Comment: Yes, @amoebasaysReinstateMonica's [comment](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/reinstate-monica/5821?noredirect=1#comment19575_5821) precisely encapsulates my thinking. After all, it seemed to me like her legal bills were covered by her GoFundMe site, and there was no countersuit by SO. It's good that we now understand each other's point, even if we draw different conclusions.

Comment: @amoeba My understanding of the legal action was to get StackOverflow to stop harming her reputation. We don't know what was in the agreement, but that was the stated aim.

Comment: @S.Kolassa The gofundme page says she still wants to be reinstated because (apparently) she does, as she indicated previously. SO can certainly do just that, simply by saying "since we removed her improperly, let's just reinstate her". I don't see anything anywhere that changed that. What she was not prepared to do (inferring from her public statements) was submit to the procedure SO laid out for moderators to be reinstated after having been properly removed, which they admitted was not the case with Monica. This seems to be the present situation (though she could also decide to apply later).

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: where on the GoFundMe site does she say so? The last thing she seems to have posted is the precise wording of the agreement that is also on Meta.SE, with a few words on what she will do with any surplus funds, nothing on her still wanting to be reinstated. Nor is there anything on [her blog](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/).

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica Sorry, I was repeating (/ responding to) something you said earlier, not re-reading the page myself; I may have read it out of context. If I screwed up, I apologize. But in any case, to my recollection she said so earlier on meta.SE, and I don't think that changed.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: yes, earlier she said that. The problem (for me) is that the last communication we got from her was that *agreement*, which to me suggests she does not wish for reinstatement any more (at least in the absence of any clear communication to the contrary from her), so as per above, I don't see the point in calling for it any more... And I agree that this comment thread is getting unwieldy.

Comment: She did not apply for the reinstatement process SO developed; she had previously indicated why she would not (while still seeking reinstatement). There was ***nothing new*** in the meta post - by the very person that publicly defamed her, for goodness sake - it was simply a re-statement that she wasn't doing what she had already told us she would not do -- which is to undergo an unfair process that assumed her guilt, and which had numerous flaws (which were discussed at length by her and others on meta). You act as if this was new; but it isn't, she already said that before the gofundme.

Comment: I expect that the conclusion you drew was very much what SO sought to get people to conclude by the way they phrased it, but it doesn't actually indicate *any change* from Monica's position as I understood it in November.

Comment: To clarify, if I recall right, the post by Sara Chipps says Monica "has not applied" for reinstatement (i.e. by their current process). Monica already indicated she had problems with it; no surprise there. It doesn't tell us that she doesn't want reinstatement. It doesn't tell us she will not apply. It just tells us that at the time of that post she had not applied; a fact at that point in time. We should be very careful not to assume it means any more than that she has not (by then) applied. . You should be free to do what you like with your username & icon, of course.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: to be honest, it seems like we are repeating the entire conversation over again I already had with gung. I see the agreement. Monica has signed it. *If I do not see anything else than such an agreement*, yes, I indeed believe that is the end of the story. If I should draw any other conclusion, I believe Monica should clarify. She has many other venues for mentioning that she indeed still wants to be reinstated. She chose not to do so. Concluding from this silence that her pre-agreement views still hold seems to me quite a leap.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: and no, I am not acting like there was anything new in that agreement. Please don't put words in my mouth. The only thing I am commenting on is that (a) Monica has signed that agreement, which in itself is indeed a new development, and (b) she has nowhere since then indicated that she nevertheless would prefer to be reinstated. Why would she not do so? The only conclusion I can draw from this is that she has closed this chapter of her life and moved on.

Comment: "I am not acting like there was anything new in that agreement" -- AFAIK we're not talking about the agreement but about the separate statement by Sara Chipps that Monica has not applied for reinstatement.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: where did I act as if this specific statement was new? It wasn't, and I am quite aware it wasn't, and I don't think I ever implied I wasn't.

Comment: In your post you quoted the statement and then specified an action you were taking as a result. What else changed between the quote and the stated action? [The offer and Monica's concerns about were all there before any of us changed avatars or usernames to call for her reinstatement. If Sara Chipps pointing out that she had not reapplied changes your behaviour, it does seem to suggest you think something new occurred]

Comment: Seems that SE contacted the Register again: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/01/02/stack_overflow_settles/

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: Monica agreed to a statement that did not include the reinstatement she had been calling for. This is a new development. And she didn't mention anywhere else that she was *still* pursuing reinstatement. I took these as meaning she doesn't pursue reinstatement.

Comment: To be honest, I am a little exasperated at reiterating my understanding over and over *and over* **AND YET OVER** again. I fail to see what's unclear about it, I truly do. I recommend [amoeba's statement](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/reinstate-monica/5821?noredirect=1#comment19575_5821), which says exactly what I have been trying to convey, and [at least gung appears to understand my position now](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/reinstate-monica/5821?noredirect=1#comment19577_5821).

Comment: I think it's time for me to take a little break. I will not be commenting in this thread any more.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica The quote in Stephan's post is not a "separate statement by Sara Chipps", it is [presumably] part of the agreement itself. I am not sure what you meant here.

Comment: @amoeba I really don't see that it can itself part of an agreement, it's a description of historical fact. That the offer and her declining to take it up at present could be explicitly mentioned in such a post *might* have been agreed, but that's not at all the same thing. It might even have been agreed that one or both parties stipulate to the offer having been made and declined, but again, that doesn't make the offer itself part of the agreement (I don't even see how that could make any sense).

Comment: ... since an agreement is where two parties each have a list of things they want and which they negotiate over and one or both compromising until both sides agree. If Monica was not seeking such an offer (and clearly wasn't), they're free to offer it or not offer it independently of an agreement (what's the leverage here? what's to gain for either side in "making the offer" and its declining being part of an agreement - they freely offer what was already on offer, she declines for already clear reasons). What's to agree anywhere in that?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I meant that the quote is taken from the *statement* that the lawyers of Monica and SE have presumably agreed upon (because the same identical statement appeared on meta.SE and Monica's gofundme page). That's all I meant. I imagine Monica and SE signed something and this something included this statement.

Answer (score 40):

Changing your username and avatar are not the only options.  People can also change the text in the 'about me' section of their user page.  Note that if your reputation is >1k, you can have an [expandable usercard](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) that will show some of the text from your about me section when someone mouses over your username on a post.

Some suggested text was first proffered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336283/187282):

> The recent actions of Stack Exchange have been reprehensible. The lack of professional conduct, the tone deaf way they've been dealing with the community, and the unfair and unjustified way they've dealt with Monica Cellio.
>
> Monica is an exemplar of the community, it's incredible how she's managed to keep a level head during this time when emotions have been very high.
>
> [REINSTATE MONICA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/187282)

---

*Update: the gofundme campaign has been closed.*

A newer option has been proffered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337034/187282).  What has changed is that Monica has started a [gofundme](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) campaign to offset the costs of legal action.  As a result, people might change their username to append "go fund Monica", instead of "reinstate Monica".  The suggested about me text is then:

> ### Consider supporting Monica Cellio's gofundme [here >>>](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users)
>
> A popular and well-respected volunteer network moderator, Monica Cellio, [was terminated without warning](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193) and [portrayed to the press as misgendering trans people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334133/187282) by Stack Overflow, Inc. All signs suggest this was an erroneous, if not malicious, decision not founded on fact, which the company is completely failing to take any responsibility for. [This has caused an enormous and ongoing uproar in the community.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/187282)
>
> Monica and the community have been quite literally **begging** for *some* kind of response from the company either opening up a path to reinstatement, or justifying their decision to terminate her, for more than a month now. She's made many good-faith offers to talk, and others have offered to mediate (and made [dozens of constructive suggestions on how to resolve the situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=monica)). Members of the Lavender community have spoken up on her behalf ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333992/187282), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336731/187282)).
>
> So far, Stack Overflow, Inc. has met all of this with thunderous silence. As a long-time contributor and someone always willing to see the good in the company's and its employees' actions and assume good faith, I'm still struggling to come to terms with the corporate callousness of this behaviour which we have to assume now is the new normal.
>
> [Having exhausted all other means of communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/187282), Monica is now raising funds for potential legal action to clear her name. This is in her own interest, but arguably also in the interest of the SO community at large. While only the libel is likely to be legally actionable, it might establish at least *some* boundaries to what the company can do to its volunteers, as well as be a symbolic slap in the face of a business that appears to have lost all respect for the community that keeps it alive.
>
> I have complete trust the funds will be used well and anything left over (say because they decide to do the right thing after all and legal action becomes unnecessary) will go toward good causes.
>
> **[Consider supporting her today.](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users)**

Comment: I wish there were an easy copy-paste that worked with links. This is a good suggestion, gung. … also, fwiw, I got my new (excellent) job through careers, and have referenced others there.  That is a source of revenue and credibility.  If CV "goes evil", then I can't in good conscience point folks I know or companies that I know to use their careers product.

Comment: @EngrStudent-ReinstateMonica, I suppose I didn't think of that.  If you click "edit", you should be able to copy & paste.

Answer (score 26):

Not just because of Monica, but I've decided to **stop contributing to StackOverflow and quit**.

Other reasons include that there was 0 progress towards improving the platform. For example, we still see tons of duplicates across the sites, but we still cannot mark a question as duplicate on stats.SE if there is a perfect answer on SO, or the other way round. I hate the overlap between SO, stats.SE, DS.SE etc. but this seems to not matter at all for the company - on the contrary, they get more views. And there is zero progress in assisting new users to not post duplicates. When a user posts a duplicate, the system should ask him to migrate the question instead, for example. Also, when posting a new user should likely be guided through some relevant similar questions, to reduce the duplicates.
Instead, the company wastes money on doomed projects such as SO Documentation and SO for teams.

In my opinion, **they have stopped listening to their users**.

Comment: Sorry to see you go!

Comment: *Cross-site duplicates*. Ditto [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com), which has tons of duplicates of things answered on SO or CrossValidated.

Comment: I've pretty much stopped answering questions for the same reason: too many cross-site duplicates. Feel like a waste of time. (Not to mention https://ai.stackexchange.com/ which is also another almost exact duplicate. I have raised the issue in dozens of posts on DS and AI SE but weirdly virtually nobody cares.) I'm also very much again the script that does auto-deletion of questions, which caused hundreds of my questions being removed. Basically I don't feel stack exchange cares much about user content, probably because they think they have too many users to care.

Comment: Not bright are they.  There are ways of contriving the answer to this that is win-win, that drives more views AND has fewer duplicates (aka less memory, compute overhead).

Answer (score -18):

First of all, all the moderators are on volunteer basis. So the site has the right to determine who gets to be moderator and who doesnt "at will". Moderators have not signed any contracts with the company,

Comment: And we have the right to be upset by it too, since we are customers of the services SE offers. Don't get your point at all.

Comment: As a customer, you have no right to tell the company officials how to run their company. Its simple, you dont like their service or decisions, you can seek help elsewhere, its free market. I cant go to McDonalds and tell the management, why did they fire Bob.

Comment: I think you've got the reasoning backwards. I can make a criticism of anyone or anything for any reason -- but they're under no obligation to do anything about it. Following your reasoning to its logical conclusion, you're suggesting that no one should be allowed to criticize BP for poisoning the Gulf of Mexico, or Boeing for killing hundreds with the 737MAX, or Arthur Anderson for cooking Enron's books. I don't know about you, but I'd prefer marine life to not be poisoned, aircraft to be flightworthy, and financial criminals pilloried... Of course, you're allowed to disagree.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica, You comment is the classical example of misdirection. You are equating apples to bananas.  There are protocols in place by the government and other parties in the form of conformity that is unlawful to neglect. Violations of those conformities by the company makes the company accountable by law. However, "the general policy" of the company to decide if they should have a printer in all the offices or only one or should the pantry be equipped with expresso machine or not or monica be fired or not, is the matter of the company only. Its not that hard to understand.

Comment: Even if we restrict the consideration to employment, (1) I'm still entitled to express an opinion about firing Monica; (2) firing Monica, besmirching her character, and disparaging her to the press is wrong; (3) and possibly illegal. If the crux of your argument is that I have no power over SO, then you're correct, but completely missing the point: **people who do dumb or bad stuff should be criticized**; that criticism has moral value; any legal characterization is *at most* one-third of the issue. Perhaps you believe SO wasn't wrong to fire Monica, but no one is above reproach.

Comment: Anyway, my point about BP, Boeing and Arthur Anderson is that *I can criticize them*. It seems that you've confused criticism and legal liability. These two things are different. Even if there's no underlying *legal wrongdoing*, I can still have an opinion and express that opinion.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica I understand your point, me and my collegue have suffered even worse, we were laid off from a tech firm due to their yearly loss, the management decided to lay us off because we were among senior member who were paid high and entitled to benefits (Not because of our performance), hence, we accepted it because we "signed a contract" before joining that the company is entitled to fire the staff without any reason. This clause in the contract mentioned "at will" and thats it. Now should we decide to be SJW and create a union, the free market wont be free anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry that you were laid off. That must have been a very trying time for you and your colleague. Your claim appears to be that because you were laid off, anyone anywhere can be laid off for any reason. But I don't understand why *your firm* laying *you* off justifies *SO* firing *Monica* and smearing her. This is an apples and bananas comparison.

Comment: If your point is that corporations are cruel and the American economy gives workers little recourse, then of course I agree with you. If you're somehow trying to use this as an example of why unions or social reforms are bad, or to show that the so-called "free market" is good, then I'm afraid you've gotten your argument backwards again.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica for your first comments, I am not using my example to justify anything. Thats how world works. Coming to the case of Monica, she was a moderator on volunteering basis, so she was not actually fired or her account was blocked. Her privileges were removed but she still could access her account, so i dont see much of an issue here. When the management decides to change the team captain of say football, should the captain start crying? No one forced her to become moderator in the first place nor the company swore any obligation to keep her as moderator indefinitely.

Comment: Anyways I dont think i can add anything to this to change your mind, it is one of those political discussions where one discusses logic and other discusses morals.

Comment: Which of your statements should be read as arguments and which are merely unrelated anecdotes? We’re not talking about an abstract situation involving football, we’re talking about what happened to Monica. Given the strange leaps of logic and selection of weird, unrelated examples to justify your position (what position? Why was it **good** to fire and disparage Monica?), it seems out you have neither logic nor morality on your side. Anyway, logic and morality aren’t exclusive positions. An entire field of philosophy dedicated to *reasoning* about what is right and just.

Comment: Ultimately, if you think that logic and morality are mutually exclusive, either you’re subscribing to bad logic or you’re subscribing to bad morals. I’ll let you sort out which is which. But I really hope you take a moment and rigorously think through why you think it’s true that it’s impossible to be both logical and moral.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica What i am saying it is neither **good** or **bad** to **demote**, (**not fire**) Monica, it is just what **owner** wants, whether you like it or not. If Mark Zuckerberg doesnt want me to open up Facebook account, I wont be able to. Now I can start SJW forum to discuss this all day long and even start GoFundMe to fight back that Mark Zuckerberg doesnt want me to be on Facebook, it wont mean a thing. Thats not how corporate world works. If my friend excludes me and invites other to his house, I will not go crazy over social media no matter how insulting it could be.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica your arguments will work well in communist setting, where public jointly holds the rights to an entity.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that just because someone *has* power, it is right use that power to do *anything* that is not explicitly illegal? Because there's a wide gap between what's right and what's illegal. **People who do bad and dumb things can be criticized.** That's my argument. Criticism won't necessarily change it, but that does nothing to invalidate the moral basis of the criticism. Our orientation to power is the most important political stance we can take, and your orientation towards power suggests an entirely authoritarian view: might makes right. As to that, *sic sepmer tyrannis*

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica Are you suggesting that if I come to your **property** to sleep in for one night because I am so tired and cant drive, you have no **right** to deny me entrance? I mean offcouse, it will be nice of you to let me in and let me sleep because "by your logic" a house is meant to be for **people to sleep in** and inviting me in is "morally right thing to do".

Comment: If your answer to above is "yes" then by that logic, yes, whatever happened with monica was not good.

Comment: I've let my friends sleep in my house when they're not able to make it home safely. But I wasn't *legally required* to do this. If I'd refused, my friends could say "Sycorax is a jerk! They made me get a cab home," and perhaps they'd be right (depending on the circumstances). My argument is that you can criticize people who do dumb and bad things. Your hypothetical doesn't disprove that claim. Another flaw with your hypothetical is that it confuses legal rights and moral stances. This is a flaw with every one of your arguments so far. Another flaw is that it places power above reproach.

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, I might be wrong. For example, I'd be wrong if I refused to let my friends stay for bad or dumb reasons, and they would be correct to criticize me. If you agree that my friends can criticize me if I made a bad or dumb decision, then you agree that we can criticize SO for demoting Monica and disparaging her. It seems you've got the argument backwards again.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica, exactly thats my whole point, your friends can claim "Sycorax is a jerk! They made me get a cab home" but that "doesnt make you wrong!", did you understand now? ...in this analogy just replace "your friends" with "all the people in this page who are making an issue" and replace "yourself" with "SE".

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica I doubt your statement that depending upon circumstances you might be wrong. We are not even questioning the reasoning. Its your property, its your will.

Comment: Again, you're making a legal claim, but my arguments hinge on the distinguishing between legal and moral arguments. Until you acknowledge that moral arguments have value, we will be at an impasse.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica I am speaking purely on the logical bases. Logically there is no right or wrong here, morally there might be opinions, but living in a world where different people have different morals and opinions, we can at-least rely on that fact that logical grounds and legal ground separates us from those personal biases.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica, looks like she has [settled on agreement with SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio?cb=1), despite all that fundraising campaign. She wont speak about the settlement amount or deal. This is **exactly** what I expected.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. The fundraising campaign raised money to hire attorneys who negotiated the settlement, whatever that entails (it's secret). Why are your expectations an relevant to this conversation?

Comment: Anyway, your argument from legality finds itself in a hard spot. Either you're assuming that all of today's laws are just, so you are implicitly making a moral argument, or you don't care if today's laws are unjust, in which case you'll tolerate any atrocity that the legal code permits. This is it is dangerous to blindly follow the law just because it's *final*, instead of seriously engaging with moral philosophy. Your legalist argument also can't answer "Should we write a new law? What should it say?" because it has no basis to reason about what a good or bad law is.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica so i guess you got me wrong. What i meant was that you guys raised funds, so that you can see the "physical outcome" of the process or policy change, but instead what happend was out of court settlement in secret. Usually, individuals do "out of court" settlement to profit from the situation, not because of the "cause" itself. If the "cause" was the priority then she should have fought in the court so everything would have been public and your donations would be fruitful as the "cause" was being upheld, not a "compromise"

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER, you've repeatedly referred to people advocating for Monica as 'social justice warriors'. Your analogy is flawed. To the extent either party is analogous to SJWs, it would be the company, which fired Monica in order to create a more welcoming environment for trans people. (Note that they failed badly on this goal.) Personally, I support a welcoming environment for everyone, but it is obvious that some of the people complaining the most are transphobes & trolls who don't really care as much about Monica. The company is explicitly following a SJW-type policy. They have said so.

Comment: The company's decisions don't make sense from a hard-nosed business perspective. They have alienated many more people than are actually trans users on the site. They have lost some of their most prolific and highest rep contributors. Those are the people who generate value for the company.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, Ok, can you then explain me that if the "cause" was legit, how come we didnt get to the the outcome? Instead, what we got was a confidential deal has been reached and this case is now settled. So much for the all the campaign and stuff.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The lawyers for the 2 sides negotiated & came to some agreement. Part of the agreement was the rule that they don't discuss it. We don't know exactly what the agreement entails, but there's no question Monica was at a disadvantage. My guess is her lawyers advised her that the agreement was the best she was likely to get. That's pretty typical of this sort of thing. Whose cause is just has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Allright, i thought it was for a holistic cause and not just monica. Offcourse she is not at disadvantage at all.